# Objective C : Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective C and trying to learn it. I am trying to write calculator program which performs simple mathematical calculation(addition, subtraction and so forth).

I want to create an array which stores for numbers(double value) and operands. Now, my pushOperand method takes ID as below:

```
-(void) pushOperand:(id)operand
{
    [self.inputStack addObject:operand];

}
```

when I try to push double value as below:

```
- (IBAction)enterPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [self.brain pushOperand:[self.displayResult.text doubleValue]];
}
```

It gives my following error: `"Sending 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'"`

I would appreciate if you guys can answer my following questions:

1. 'id' is a generic type so I would assume it will work with any type without giving error above. Can you please help me understand the real reason behind the error?
2. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a *pointer to any class*.  Hence, it does not work with primitive types such as `double` or `int` which are neither pointers, nor objects.  To store a primitive type in an NSArray, one must first wrap the primitive in an `NSNumber` object.  This can be done in using alloc/init or with the new style object creation, as shown in the two snippets below.

**old style**

```
NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[self.displayResult.text doubleValue]];
[self.brain pushOperand:number];
```

**new style**

```
NSNumber *number = @( [self.displayResult.text doubleValue] );
[self.brain pushOperand:number];
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using it with an `NSNumber`: Try not to abuse using `id` where you don't need to; lots of issues can arise if not.

```
- (void)pushOperand:(NSNumber *)operand
{
    [self.inputStack addObject:operand];
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.brain pushOperand:@([self.displayResult.text doubleValue])];
}
```

Comment: You should also be able to use the short-hand @([self.displayResult.text doubleValue]) rather than [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[self.displayResult.text doubleValue]] to make it a bit more concise, but yes you can't push primitives into an objective-C array or pass as a generic objective-c object (id) because it's not an object.